# Columns containing circles overlap vertically in Bootrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to achieve the look displayed in the image below with 'Bootstrap 4'. What I achieved is partly what I want, because there is too much vertical distance between the dots.

[image]

I first tried nesting the cols and then I used negative 'margins', but it didn't help move the circles vertically closer to each other. Is it even possible to make the 'cols' "overlap", or do I have to find another way to achieve the Look I want?

```css
.block {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.circle {
  background-color: darkred;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 200px;
  height: 110px;
  width: 110px;
  display: table;
  /* margin-bottom: -50px; */

}
.circle p {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<!--Circles-->
  <div class="row no-gutters justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-lg-3 ">
      <div class="col-lg-2 block">
        <div class="circle   ">
          <p>Circle 1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 block offset-5">
        <div class="circle  ">
          <p>Circle 2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 block ">
        <div class="circle  ">
          <p>Circle 3</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 block  offset-5 ">
        <div class="circle  ">
          <p>Circle 4</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 block ">
        <div class="circle  ">
          <p>Circle 5</p>
        </div>
      </div>
<!-- Text-->
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-7 ">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et
        dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve by `Bootstrap4` predefined classes.
Take a div and define `class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"` & inside this div take two another div with `class="col-5 px-0"` so in *left side* div define `circle div` **1,3,5** and *right side* div define `circle div` **2,4**, 
For `.circle` define `width:100%`, `height:0`, so height will auto equal to width from this padding technique like `padding-top: 50%` & `padding-bottom: 50%` so from this technique to `circle` will responsive and resize as per parent div width.

```css
.circle {
  background-color: #E94954;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.circle p{
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 90%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container my-3">
  <div class="row no-gutters justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class="col-5 px-0">
          <div class="circle">
            <p>Circle 1</p>
          </div>
          <div class="circle">
            <p>Circle 3</p>
          </div>
          <div class="circle">
            <p>Circle 5</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-5 px-0">
          <div class="circle">
            <p>Circle 2</p>
          </div>
          <div class="circle">
            <p>Circle 4</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-8 col-lg-7">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        <br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple idea using flex you can use BS flex classes as well

```css
.box {
    display: flex;
        align-items: center;
}
.containerr {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
      margin-right: 16px;
}
.holder {
  margin: 1%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  
   background: red;
}
.holder:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<div class="containerr">
  <div class="holder "></div>
  <div class="holder "></div>
  <div class="holder "></div>
</div>
<div class="containerr">
  <div class="holder "></div>
  <div class="holder "></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<style>
    .block {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.circle {
    background-color: darkred;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 200px;
    height: 110px;
    width: 110px;
    display: table;
    margin-bottom:1vw;

}
.circle p {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;

}
    </style>
<body>

<!--Circles-->
    <div class="row no-gutters justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-lg-1 ">
        <div class="col-lg-2 block">
          <div class="circle">
            <p>Circle 1</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-1 block ">
          <div class="circle  ">
            <p>Circle 3</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-1 block ">
          <div class="circle  ">
            <p>Circle 5</p>
          </div>
        </div>
<!-- Text-->
      </div>
      <div style="margin-top: 4vw; margin-left: -2 vw;"class="col-lg-1 ">
       <div class="col-lg-1 block ">
          <div class="circle  ">
            <p>Circle 2</p>
          </div>
        </div>
 <div class="col-lg-1 block   ">
          <div class="circle  ">
            <p>Circle 4</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      <div  class="col-lg-3 ">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et
          dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to use two separate col classes when making these 5 circle. 3 in one col and next 2 circles in other col.
Here is the html+CSS code for the
 display that you wanted!

Comment: But from this structure to we can not set responsive circle so how can we set this structure on small screen without write css media query?